# Can't create game controller button group in tailwind-css

Tags: php, html, css, web, tailwind-css

im trying to create game controller button group in tailwindcss. [this is what i want to develop exactly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GF04X.png) but i cant do it can anyone help me please ?

(Sorry for my english im not good at it.)

Comment: `<div class="flex mt-4">
                <button type="button" class="w-[40px] h-[40px] bg-[url('/public/polygon.png')] bg-no-repeat bg-contain ml-4 mt-16"></button>
                <button type="button" class="w-[40px] h-[40px] bg-[url('/public/polygon.png')] bg-no-repeat bg-contain mr-4 rotate-180 mt-36"></button>
            </div>` i tried this but it was so hard to fit them.

Comment: And i tried the Absolute but it wasnt worked for me :/

Comment: Rather than adding details in comments, please [edit] your question to add  information. Comments here may get hidden by "show more comments" or could be deleted without notice. Editing updates into your question ensures that they don't get lost and that everybody who wants to answer the question sees them.

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="flex mt-4 bg-[#00567d] relative w-40 h-40 p-4">
    <button type="button" class="w-0 h-0 border-l-[25px] border-r-[25px] border-b-[35px] border-solid border-l-transparent border-r-transparent border-b-white  bg-no-repeat bg-contain absolute top-2 left-1/2 -translate-x-1/2"></button>
    <button type="button" class="w-0 h-0 border-t-[25px] border-b-[25px] border-r-[35px] border-solid border-t-transparent border-b-transparent border-r-white bg-no-repeat bg-contain absolute left-2 top-1/2 -translate-y-1/2"></button>
    <button type="button" class="w-0 h-0 border-l-[25px] border-r-[25px] border-t-[35px] border-solid border-l-transparent border-r-transparent border-t-white bg-no-repeat bg-contain absolute bottom-2 left-1/2 -translate-x-1/2"></button>
    <button type="button" class="w-0 h-0 border-t-[25px] border-b-[25px] border-l-[35px] border-solid border-t-transparent border-b-transparent border-l-white bg-no-repeat bg-contain absolute right-2 top-1/2 -translate-y-1/2"></button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```